# Drop a column that was used as 'by' argument in join

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following query:

```
library(dplyr)
FinalQueryDplyr <- PostsWithFavorite %>%
  inner_join(Users, by = c("OwnerUserId" = "Id"), keep = FALSE) %>%
  select(DisplayName, Age, Location, FavoriteTotal, MostFavoriteQuestion, MostFavoriteQuestionLikes) %>%
  select(-c(OwnerUserId)) %>%
  arrange(desc(FavoriteTotal))
```

As you can see, I use the `OwnerUserId` column as the joining column between 2 data frames.

I want the result data frame to only have other columns, without the `OwnerUserId` column visible.

Even though I 'deselect' the `OwnerUserId` column 2 times in said query:

- once by not including it in the first `select` clause
- once by explicitly deselecting it with `select(-c(OwnerUserId))`

It is still visible in the result:
`OwnerUserId DisplayName Age Location FavoriteTotal MostFavoriteQuestion MostFavoriteQuestionLikes`

How can I get rid of the column that was used as a joining column in dplyr?

Comment: Without being able to work with your data, it's pretty hard to know what's going on. A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Can't do any more than guess, but is the data frame grouped by that column?

Comment: Have you tried `ungroup`ing? That's the most probable reason I can think of. If a var is a grouping var, dyplr will not (de-)select it.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly it. ungroup() was the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to remove the attribute by converting to data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
PostsWithFavorite %>%
   inner_join(Users, by = c("OwnerUserId" = "Id"), keep = FALSE) %>%
   select(DisplayName, Age, Location, FavoriteTotal, 
          MostFavoriteQuestion, MostFavoriteQuestionLikes) %>%
   as.data.frame %>%
   select(-c(OwnerUserId)) %>%
   arrange(desc(FavoriteTotal))
```